# Sitecore SXA few components disappearing

Tags: sxa

In one of our websites, **the header and footer disappears after a while**. And this is **happening only for the home page**.
After we **recycle the app pool or publish something** then it starts showing up again.
We are using SXA and upgraded it from 1.6 to 1.8

This website has two CDs. What we are seeing is that on CD1 we see the header and footer, but on CD2 the header and footer disappears.

Comment: Have you compared the file systems of your two CDs to ensure their configs are the same?

Comment: @JasonSt-Cyr the configs are exactly the same.

Comment: Sounds kind of like a weird html caching issue, since a publish of content, causes the header and footer to display again.  What caching settings do you have enabled for the header/footer components?

Comment: @DylanYoung even while removing the cacheable setting, the issue is occurring.

Comment: I have seen this issue when there is a problem with the optimized-min items for the theme. Try deleting them and publishing so they are deleted (and auto recreated on Web).